# 404 Not Found nginx/1.6.3

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, http-status-code-404

i just setup my VPS with engine-x. 
All working very well. when someone type a URL of my domain.com/... and there is no matching file,its show a simple 404 not found error page. 
Now i want to redirect all these visitors who mistype a URL,they will redirect to my main domain. 
I search on google and here,i try all these .htaccess method like putting 
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/errors/404.php [L]`

on a .htaccess file of the server root directory which is `/var/www/mydomain.com/html`
.and server block method for engine-x. But nothing workout. can anyone please help me?

Comment: Nginx does not read it htaccess files. You need to use a location block and rewrite instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nginx rewrite rules in nginx config file.

Something like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    . . .

    error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
    location = /custom_404.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            internal;
    }
```

}

Comment: I edit nginx conf file and then restart nginx but not working. here is my conf file http://pastebin.com/YWGyMSS3